# Get data in a nested JSON format in Meteor

Tags: javascript, json, meteor

When I check my collection via the command below:

> collection.find().fetch();

It gives me the data that looks like this:

```
_id: RXRHNcPofuX7wFhJm,

data: "{ "package" : "testpackage", 
         "prodId" : "skvicowMSDjtKDxsP", 
         "timePurchase" : "1455417282379.000000"}"
```

I not sure how to get the **timePurchase**  value under **data**.

In my MeteorJS tried using:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
'getData' : function () {
    return collection.find().fetch();
  },
});
```

In my HTML I did it like this:

```
{{#each getData}}
{{data.timePurchase}}
{{/each}}
```

But it is not working. Please help. Thanks

Comment: I believe, you will have to use `JSON.parse()`. try: `data: JSON.parse(...)`

Comment: @Rajesh - do need to assign the "collection.find()" to a variable then parse and return the value?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I dont have any idea about `meteor`. But the JSON that you have given in question is not an object. Its a string representation of object. Hence I suggested you to use `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.fetch()` and try as you did. In chrome console only we have to mention .fetch()

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but still not working. I added fetch because "collection.find();" alone does not work.

Comment: I think you are json object declartion in mongo might be wrong.              id: RXRHNcPofuX7wFhJm,

data: { "package" : "testpackage", 
         "prodId" : "skvicowMSDjtKDxsP", 
         "timePurchase" : "1455417282379.000000"}

Comment: I know now why it won't display, the value of data which looks like a JSON or object is a string that is why it starts with double quote and ends with double quote.

Comment: I got it sorted out, I parsed the string to JSON format and the stored it in an array since EACH only accepts array and done. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
'getData' : function () {
    var x = collection.find().fetch();
    var getRawData = [];
    for(var i in x) {
      if(x.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        getRawData.push(JSON.parse(x[i].data));
        console.log(getRawData);
        return getRawData;
      }
    }
  }
```

case solved . . :)